# If statement that checks if a class name is equal to some name

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm making a game with js and jquery, and I have 2 players that need to spawn randomly.
The game map is composed of tiles and some of the tiles are blocked(the player can't click on them), they have a class of "unavaliable" and I need to make it so that when the players spawn, they don't spawn on those tiles that are blocked. The question is, can you make an if statement that checks if the tile has a certain class, and if it does, then don't spawn the player there. What I have for now is:

```
// This asigns 2 random tiles for player one and player two
let randomSpawn = tiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length)];
let randomSpawnTwo = tiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length)];
/* This is an if statement that chekcs if the class name coresponds to unavaliable*/

function checkIfempty(){

    if(randomSpawn.className === "unavaliable"){
        randomSpawn = tiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length)]
        console.log('heyo it does')
    }else if(randomSpawn.classname !== "unavaliable"){
        randomSpawn.appendChild(playerOne);
    }

    if(randomSpawnTwo.className === "unavaliable"){
        randomSpawnTwo = tiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length)];
    }else if(randomSpawnTwo.className !== "unavaliable"){
        randomSpawnTwo.appendChild(playerTwo);
    }
}
```

So what I bassically want, is, if the already assigned random tile has a class of "unavaliable", pick another random field, and place the player there. This of course doesn't work for some reason that I'm unaware of.
And the function is set to run on load.

Comment: What behaviour are you encountering, and how is it different from the expected behaviour?

Comment: Are `tiles` and `tile` arrays of HTMLElements?

Comment: So it all loads perfectly normal, it asignes the players to random fields, but, on some page reloads, it happens that this if statements are ignored, and players get spawned on the tiles that have a class name of "unavaliable:

Comment: @Luca Yes they are.

Comment: @Luca, I'm sorry, bad copy/paste, both have the name of "tiles"

Comment: Likely you'll want to regenerate a random tile `while` the `className` value isn't `unavailable`. You're checking once, and regenerating, but it's possible that two times in a row you pick a tile that's blocked. Basically, using a while loop is one option. Maybe just step through your changes in your browser's debugger to better understand the flow of assignment.

Comment: Thanks @clint! So the code as it is now makes sense?

Comment: `if(randomSpawn.constructor.name == 'unavailable')`?

Comment: See the jQuery method `hasClass()` or the native Javascript `.classList.contains()` method.

Comment: You don't need to use `else if` when the second condition is the exact opposite of the first condition. Just use `else`.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried using both hasclass and classlist contains, neither of them worked so I've returned to using .classname. And as for the else if, I know, I just wanted to make sure it executes, I don't trust in else statements hahah

Comment: The problem with using `.className` is that it won't work if the object has multiple classes. E.g. `class="unavailable active"`.

Comment: @Barmar Alright, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to `.filter()` the tiles first? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Thanks @Barmar and @clint! By combining while loop with hasclass I've managed to solve the problem! I've reloaded the page approximately 100 times and the players didn't spawn on unavaliable fields!

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode 404 not found :D

Comment: In comments, square brackets go around the link name, parentheses go around the URL. Remove the `]` from the end of the URL and it will work.

Comment: typo. Filtering would return only available tiles and would remove the if/then checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a loop to keep checking whether the selected tile is available. However, this will become slow when most tiles are unavailable, since it will have to repeat many times.

Instead of picking a random tile from the array and checking whether it's available, you could simply use a selector that only returns available tiles.

Give all your tiles a class like `tile`, and then use:

```
var availableTiles = $(".tile:not(.unavailable)");
var randomSpawn = availableTiles.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * availableTiles.length));
availableTiles = availableTiles.not(randomSpawn); // remove the one we just selected
randomSpawn2 = availableTiles.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * availableTiles.length));
```